# Simple function java String to Int / Reverse

Tags: java

I want to generate a `String` with `11` digits from an ID.
For example: 
an account with an `ID=12` would give `00000000012`

And after that I need to retrieve this id from the string.

For example: 
a string with `00000000022` give an `ID=22`

Comment: Why do the ids need to be the same length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To format the string, use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
int n = 123;
String.format("%011d", 123);
// ===> 00000000123
```

To get the number back from string, use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

```
Integer.parseInt("00000000123");
// ====> 123
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer from String to int use `Integer.parseInt()`

However, for creating the String I would suggest:

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
    thestring="0"+thestring;
}
```

replace 10 with how many zeros you need.

Also you could just use java.text.DecimalFormat, your choice.

Or combine both:

```
int lengthID=10;
String zeros="";
for(int x=0;x<lengthID;x++){
    zeros="0"+zeros;
}
java.text.DecimalFormat id=new java.text.DecimalFormat(zeros);
```

Comment: thestring="0"+thestring; is very costly